# Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many - "should" or "must"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Or: "What happens if you decide wrong"

Doc says:

> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks,
>   or extra attributes on the join model.

But should the "*you should use*" be a "*you must use*"?

The point is, we have **one attribute** in a join table, and this one is **heavily discussed**.

So what happens if I (we) decide to use the simpler HABTM and in one year the friendly attribute pops up? Is it possible to access it (more complex, ok), or have we go back to start and redesign?

All the answers (and there are a lot of) to this - "HABTM or :through", are more or less easy to decide; "take this or the other".

I want to know how to correct the error if we decide wrong.

Is it eg. possible to "push a model between", or how to access this one attribute, if it pops up?

Or is the better strategy to start with :through? just for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to convert a HABTM into a HMT.

The join table follows a naming convention of table + table in lexical order like "developers_projects".

Later, if you want to make the relationship HMT just create a model called `DevelopersProject` and use that as the join table.  It's the same table.  But you can then use migrations to add fields, and use the model to add validations, etc. etc.

The advantage of starting with HMT is that you get to call the join table whatever you want, but that's not hugely important.

Comment: I was pretty sure to hear that, so the "should" stays a "should", and in my (our) case its the safer way (attribb stays <5%)

Comment: Yes, there's some cases where it's clear HABTM is exactly all you need... like, for example, pictures that belong to categories, a picture can belong to many categories, a category can have many pictures, but there's absolutely no information you need about the relationship other than it exists.   But if you have Teachers / Students via Courses or Doctors / Patients via Appointments then clearly there's information you want to know about the relationship (date, time, classroom, etc.).

Comment: in my case: page belongs to book, picture to page. now page belongs to 1 or more books (excerpt) - and the picture is only shown in main book, or not

Comment: Oh, interesting... so the bonus attribute is "includes/excludes images". Intriguing app.

Comment: exactly, for copyright reasons, i am sure this attribute will never be on

Comment: and I like "bonus attribute" description